# How to prove the expression is not a square in the following question

Tags: number-theory

Let d be any positive integer not equal to 2,5 or 13. Show that one can find distinct a, b in the set 2,5,13,d such that ab-1 is not a perfect square.

I tried it for a long time but couldn't figure out a solution.....help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the numbers  a   and b  must be differents .
My idea is to consider the map  f from  {2,5, 13, d} x {2,5, 13, d} to  Z / 4Z which to  (a, b) associated  the class of  (ab-  1), and to prouve  that  always,  the fibre f ^ -1 ({cl (2)})  or  f ^ -1 ({cl (3)}) is not empty for all  integer d.